# What is the best way to set up multiple I/O buffers in Julia?

Tags: io, buffer, julia

I am experimenting with different methods of dealing with long text strings (e.g. book length) in Julia. Specifically I am looking at transposition ciphers and have been testing speed and memory usage using (1) string concatenation, (2) arrays and (3) I/O buffers. In the last case I need to be able to 'print' individual characters to different, indexable, I/O buffers. My first (simplified) attempt was as follows:

```
text = fill(IOBuffer(), 3)
print(text[1], 'a')
print(text[2], 'b')
print(text[3], 'c')
for i in 1:3
    println(String(take!(text[i])))
end
```

This produces:

```
"abc"
""
""
```

In other words, the first index returned the whole string `"abc"` rather than just the desired character `'a'`, and the other indices produced empty strings `""` as the buffer was reset after the first `take!()` function.

My next attempt worked, but does not seem very sophisticated:

```
text = Vector(3)
for i in 1:3
    text[i] = IOBuffer()
end
print(text[1], 'a')
print(text[2], 'b')
print(text[3], 'c')
for i in 1:3
    println(String(take!(text[i])))
end
```

This produces the required output:

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
```

I'm still not entirely sure why the first method fails and the second works, but does anyone know a better method for setting up multiple I/O buffers that can be written to using indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that in `text = fill(IOBuffer(), 3)` the call `IOBuffer()` is evaluated only once so all entries of `text` are pointing to the same object. You can check it by running:

```
julia> all(x->x===text[1], text)
true
```

Or you can see this when you run:

```
julia> fill(println("AAA"), 3)
AAA
3-element Array{Void,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
```

to find that `println` was called only once - before passing its value to `fill` method.

The simplest way to solve it is to use a comprehension:

```
julia> text = [IOBuffer() for i in 1:3]
3-element Array{Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}},1}:
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> map(x->x===text[1], text)
3-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
 false
 false
```

or `map` (a bit less clean):

```
julia> map(i->IOBuffer(), 1:3)
3-element Array{Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}},1}:
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> map(x->x===text[1], text)
3-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
 false
 false
```

Actually you could fill the array with `IOBuffer` types and `invoke` them (it is not a recommended approach, but shows you the difference):

```
julia> text = invoke.(fill(IOBuffer, 3), [Tuple{}])
3-element Array{Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}},1}:
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)
 IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> map(x->x===text[1], text)
3-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
 false
 false
```

Finally, one catch to remember, as discussed [here](https://juliasnippets.blogspot.com/2018/02/a-small-adventure-into-julia-macro-land.html), is that a comprehension will invoke a function for each entry of a created array, but if you use a macro, it will be called only once. Here is a short example explained in the link in detail:

```
julia> rx = [Regex("a") for i in 1:3]
3-element Array{Regex,1}:
 r"a"
 r"a"
 r"a"

julia> map(x->x===rx[1], rx)
3-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
 false
 false

julia> rx = [r"a" for i in 1:3]
3-element Array{Regex,1}:
 r"a"
 r"a"
 r"a"

julia> map(x->x===rx[1], rx)
3-element Array{Bool,1}:
 true
 true
 true
```

Comment: Both the comprehension and map solutions work nicely, I'll go with the former as it's a little neater. Thanks.